# Reference to template type in template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

If I have a template class A, like this

```
template <int n>
class A{
    /* some code */
};
```

Is it possible to have a template class B, that takes a reference or pointer to an A as parameter without having the int n as template parameter in B.

The following code would work:

```
template <int n, A<n> &a>
class B{
    /* some code */
};
```

But to use this, I always have to supply 2 parameters to B, which would work, but is inconvenient.

In c++17 using auto would work like this

```
template <auto &a>
class B{
    /* some code */
};
```

But I have to work with the arm-none-eabi-gcc which apparently does not support c++17.

So I'd like to know, if there is any other way of creating such a template, so that B only needs 1 template argument.

Comment: `void*` for one argument :( ... In pre C++17, traditional way is 2 arguments: `<typename T, T&a>`

Comment: But when using void*, then I would still need to know the exact type in order to call a function on it, right?

Comment: Yes, `void*` is not a viable solution if you still need the type.

Comment: Then I guess I'll have to use 2 arguments, not as clean as I'd like, but it works

Comment: MACRO to avoid repetition of `decltype(var), (var)` might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the goal is to get the template argument of `A` and make sure that the type `B` is instantiated with is actually an `A`.  You can do this with some simple metaprogramming by defining your own type traits for `A`.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <int n>
class A {};

template <typename T>
struct is_A : std::false_type {};

template <int m>
struct is_A<A<m>> : std::true_type {
    static constexpr int const n = m;
};

template <typename A>
class B {
    static_assert(is_A<A>::value,"!");
    static constexpr int const n = is_A<A>::n;
};

int main() {
    B<A<1>>{};
}
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NlfQfPexXp5Z04cK)